# 7, 4, 2 WEEKDAY reminders Calculated field

Tags: sharepoint-designer, calculated-column

I have workflow to send a reminder to a manager if a new hire's start date is 7, 4, and 2 WEEKDAYS away from today's date. The calculated fields works fine as long as it's more than 7 business days from today that the employee starts. They get the 7 day, then 4 day, then 2 day (all weekday/business day calculations). My issue is that if we have a new hire starting in 3 days, the manager still gets all 3 reminders. How can I get the workflow to not kick off the 7 day email if it's 6 days away, not get the 4 day if it's 3 days away, etc. My workflow looks like this:

[image]

and my 7, 4, and 3 day calculations for the fields look like this:

7 Business Days:

=IF(WEEKDAY([Hire Date])>1,[Hire Date]-11,IF(WEEKDAY([Hire Date])>3,[Hire Date]-9,IF(WEEKDAY([Hire Date])>5,[Hire Date]-9)))

4 Business Days:
=IF(WEEKDAY([Hire Date])>1,[Hire Date]-6,IF(WEEKDAY([Hire Date])>5,[Hire Date]-4))

2 Business Days:

=IF(WEEKDAY([Hire Date])>1,[Hire Date]-4,IF(WEEKDAY([Hire Date])>3,[Hire Date]-2))

Maybe I need an variable before each email send?

Answer (score 0):

Add another calculated field which gives you the difference between StartDate and HireDate.

Now before each pause add a condition that checks the number of days. In case of enough days then do pause.